# Wrong UUID format for bluetooth python server script

Tags: python, bluetooth, debian

I can't run python bluetooth server on Debian 11 with external bluetooth module. Problem with UUID:

```
import bluetooth
import uuid as UUID
import os

os.system('sudo systemctl start bluetooth')
os.system('sudo bluetoothctl power on')
os.system('sudo bluetoothctl discoverable on')

server = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
while True:
    try:
         server.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
         break
    except Exception as e:
         print(f"Bind failed. Error: {str(e.args)}")
         print("Trying again...")
         server.close()
         break

server.listen(1)
port = server.getsockname()[1]
client = {}

#uuid = UUID.uuid4()
uuid = UUID.UUID('0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')

bluetooth.advertise_service(server, "Device Server", service_id=uuid)
```

as result:

```
Server start failed. Error: ('invalid UUID specified for service_id',)
Trying again...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/billy/BluetoothServer/./server.py", line 87, in <module>
    bluetooth.advertise_service(server, "Device Server", service_id=uuid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 259, in advertise_service
    raise ValueError (**"invalid UUID specified for service_id"**)
ValueError: invalid UUID specified for service_id
```

As I see, some error with UUID format. But what?

I try generate UUID, try use UUID form

```
bluetooth show

        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

But no differs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.